# Split checkboxes in fieldset into two columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split up checkboxes in the same fieldset into two columns using CSS.

For example, my code is below:

```
<div id="topicsbox">
    <label class="topicsname">Topics*</label>
    <label class="description">Select topic areas for which you would like to receive future updates from CTU (articles, blog posts, white papers, etc.). Check all that apply:</label>
    <div id="topicsmessage" class="messagebox"></div>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="AllTopStories" value="1098375" /><label for="AllTopStories">All Top Stories</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="BusinessandManagement" value="1098376" /><label for="BusinessandManagement">Business and Management</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="CareerandProfessional" value="1098377" /><label for="CareerandProfessional">Career and Professional</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="CriminalJustice" value="1098378" /><label for="CriminalJustice">Criminal Justice</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="HealthcareAdministration" value="1098379" /><label for="HealthcareAdministration">Healthcare Administration</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="HomelandSecurity" value="1098380" /><label for="HomelandSecurity">Homeland Security</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" id="ITEngineeringComputerScience" value="1098381" /><label for="ITEngineeringComputerScience">IT, Engineering, Computer Science</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the correct CSS to split up this list into 4 input checkboxes on the left and 3 on the right?

Comment: Float half left and half right.

Comment: What if you set the width of fieldset and input/label fields and then float them?

Comment: I'm going to try first wrapping the input in the label field and then float left and float right on appropriate label id's, as a modification of the answer from @j08691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting the css for inputs and labels as follows:

- Set proper width
- Set display: inline-block

So that you escape the need for a clear div that you will need in case of just floating them

You can also go for the CSS3 solution of

```
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The column count property in CSS is pretty helpful. If you put a line break after each form element you can make a pretty clean presentation. Also, by adding <span style="white-space: nowrap;">, it keeps the label attached to the check box element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here are a bunch of check boxes and their labels laid out nicely
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">

<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some topic" id="some id" /><label for="stuff about a topic">something for you to read</label></span><br/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```